# Algorithm to find and print figures that are common to two given long integers

Tags: c

Please help me with the appropriate C algorithm without using arrays.

Example:

Input

123456789

2037

Output

Common figures are 2, 3, 7.

My failed attempt:

```
long a, b, original_a, original_b;
int i, j, figure_a, figure_b;

printf("a=");
scanf_s("%li", &a);
printf("b=");
scanf_s("%li", &b);

original_a = a;
original_b = b;

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++){
            a = original_a;
            b = original_b;

            while (a||b){
            figure_a = a % 10;
            figure_b = b % 10;

            a /= 10;
            b /= 10;

            if (i == figure_a && j == figure_b && i == j)
                printf("%d, ", i);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How would you tell your 5-year old nephew to do that (with pen and paper)? That's your algorithm :)

Comment: If you are interested in the decimal representation of a number, why exactly are you converting it to a (binary) integer at all?

Comment: If you are going to `scanf()` the numbers from the user, use *string* to avoid unnecessary conversions. Your algorithm would then work for numbers or names or whatever.

Comment: I don't know that and where I'm doing that.

Comment: I don't know how to use string. I'm doing beginner exercises and learning to use instructions.

Comment: Some  `{` and `}` are missing, that could be a beginning to have something working

Comment: @RabbitH. - edit your last comment into your post please.  (and if you actually mean _arrays_ then say arrays.  eg.  abelenky's answer does not use vectors, just arrays.

Comment: I'm beginner trying to learn on my own, not sure yet what vectors and arrays specifically are. Hope to find out soon. The set of exercises I'm working on right now does not involve such. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fun little problem.

I threw together a quick, simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int d[10]={0};
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    while(a)
    {
        d[a%10] = 1;
        a /= 10;
    }

    while(b)
    {
        if (d[b%10]) d[b%10]=2;
        b /= 10;
    }

    for(a=0;a<10;++a) if (d[a]==2) printf("%d ", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Link to [IDE One code](https://ideone.com/iJwjsR)

---

Here's a short version that does not use arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    while(a)
    {
        c = b;
        while(c)
        {
            if (c%10 == a%10)
            {
                printf("%d ", c%10);
                break;
            }
            c /= 10;
        }
        a /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This version runs slower than my first one, and does not print out the numbers in ascending order.

Comment: Well, the OP's example doesn't show what to do if one of the numbers contains a digit multiple times. I'd expect the OP to want such a digit to only be printed once. So if the OP could clarify what `a = 1, b = 11111` should produce, that would probably help.

Comment: Addressed your concerns:  Now numbers are only printed once, and only in ascending order.

Comment: if a=1 and b=11111 the result should be 1

Answer (score 4):

You can convert both the integers to strings and then compare each character of the first string with the second one to check whether any of them matches or not. I've used nested for loops for comparing.

I've used strings because comparing each character of two strings is a lot easier than comparing each digit of two integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int a,b;
    int i,j;

    scanf("%ld %ld",&a,&b); //taking both inputs

    char temp_a[50],temp_b[50];


    sprintf(temp_a, "%ld", a); //converting the first integer to a string
    sprintf(temp_b, "%ld", b); //converting the second integer to a string


    int length_a=strlen(temp_a); //length of first string
    int length_b=strlen(temp_b); //length of second string

    // matching whether any character is in common using nested for-loops
    // printing the character as soon as it matches
    // if a character matches, the loop breaks.

    for(i=0 ; i<length_a ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<length_b ; j++)
        {
            if(temp_a[i]==temp_b[j])
            {
                printf("%c",temp_a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Providing a working example is good, but can you explain, at least just a little, what you did to address the problem?  ( Before _Hope this helps._ would be a good place. )

Comment: @ryyker thankyou for your suggestion, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

May it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int original_a, original_b, i;
short digit_a, digit_b, digit_common;
short find_digit(int num);
int main()
{
printf("Insert 2 numbers a and b\n");
scanf("%d %d", &original_a, &original_b);
digit_a = find_digit(original_a);
digit_b = find_digit(original_b);
digit_common = digit_a & digit_b;
printf("digit_common: %x\n", digit_common);
printf("Common digits of a and b\n");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(digit_common & (1<<i)){
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

```
short find_digit(int num){
short result = 0;
while(num>0){
    result |= (1 << (num%10));
    num /= 10;
}
return result;
```

}